# Indicate, specify or describe?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, word-difference

I have a form which sends an email. It has a subject and a message, and if you leave the subject empty it says:

> Please **indicate/specify/describe/a better one?** the subject briefly.

Which one is correct and why?

Comment: Since it's a form, why not use '***fill in***'?

Comment: Also, this is an example of **[Proofreading](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)**. Kindly refrain from putting up posts to check the validity of a sentence for personal use. Questions such as these can be qualified to being closed as off-topic.

Comment: @VarunKN: [It really isn't proofreading in the slightest](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/2528/stop-throwing-proofreading-close-reason-at-questions-that-are-clearly-limited). There's nothing wrong with checking a sentence for personal, business, or other use, so long as it's possible for others to make use of the question. The key to that is to make the question specific enough that it focuses on some particular point or aspect, rather than simply going through a sentence or a paragraph and looking for whatever errors may show up.

Comment: @VarunKN the text in the close reason should already give a hint: *unless a specific source of concern in the text is clearly identified*. Yes, it's proofreading but in this form, it's (IMHO) on-topic.

Comment: Please enter a brief subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Please indicate/specify/**describe**/a better one? the subject
>   briefly.

However, I would not use that on a form. I'd use:

1. Subject field must be filled in.
2. Please fill in the subject before sending.
3. Required field.

Here they indicate necessary fields with a red (*) asterisk. The fields must be filled in before the page will send or complete. The usual message is : **Required field**